# How to show that a self-complementary graph must have $4k$ or $4k+1$ vertices

Tags: graph-theory

How do I prove that a self-complementary graph must have $4k$ or $4k+1$ vertices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that a complete graph on $n$ vertices has $\frac12n(n-1)$ edges.  For a graph to be self-complimentary, it must then have half that many edges, or $\frac14n(n-1)$.  For that to be an integer, $4|n(n-1)\implies n=4k$ or $n=4k+1$

Comment: How can complement of a complete graph exist?

Comment: That's not what I'm saying (though obviously the complement of the complete graph is $\emptyset$).  Take a graph $G$ on $n$ vertices such that $G\cup G'=K_n$ and $G=G'$.  Then $|E(G)|=\frac12|E(K_n)|=\frac14n(n-1)$, where $E(G)$ is the set of edges in $G$.