# Question about self-complementary graphs

Tags: graph-theory, induction

*Question*
Prove that for every integer k≥1, exists a **self-complementary** graph with 4k vertices half of which are of degree 2k-1 and the other half of degree 2k.

*My approach*
So, I think the easiest way to prove what is asked is by induction. I can prove the base case for k=1, but as far as the inductive step is concerned, I cannot seem to reach a conclusion as to why if the statement holds for n, then it holds for n+1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try first to draw such a graph for $k=2$ or $k=3$.

Comment: Any way @MishaLavrov does for every 4n or 4n+1 exists self complementary graph?

Comment: @MishaLavrov I tried to draw such graph and I think that I achieved it for k=2, but when k=3 I need to add 19 edges (in total 33) which is neither convenient nor extremely helpful (for me).

Comment: @MariaMazur The answet to your question is yes. Check this post: (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609122/how-to-show-that-a-self-complementary-graph-must-have-4k-or-4k1-vertices )

Comment: @Chrysa My question goes the other way.

Comment: @MariaMazur I must have misread your comment. I see what you are asking now. I do not know the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple direct construction of a self-complementary graph $G$ on $4k$ vertices where all vertices have degree $2k$ or $2k-1$.

$V(G)=A\cup B\cup C\cup D$ where $A,B,C,D$ are disjoint $k$-element sets.
$$a\in A\implies N(a)=(A\setminus\{a\})\cup B.$$
$$b\in B\implies N(b)=A\cup C.$$
$$c\in C\implies N(c)=B\cup D.$$
$$d\in D\implies N(d)=C\cup(D\setminus\{d\}).$$

Let $\varphi:V(G)\to V(G)$ be a bijection such that $\varphi(A)=B$, $\varphi(B)=D$, $\varphi(C)=A$, and $\varphi(D)=C$; then $\varphi$ is an anti-automorphism of $G$, showing that $G$ is self-complementary.

A vertex $v$ has degree $2k$ if $v\in B\cup C$, degree $2k-1$ if $v\in A\cup D$.