# Does in a simple graph $G$ with $100$ vertices where $G \cong \bar G$ exist a vertex with a degree of $50$

Tags: graph-theory

Does, in a simple graph $G$ with $100$ vertices where $G \cong \bar G$, exist a vertex with a degree of $50$?

So I think that the simple graph $G$ can be isomorphic with $\bar G$ iff $|V(G)| = \frac {C_{100}^2}{2}$, so we can divide $G$ into $2$ parties: the complete graph $K_{50}$ and the edgeless graph, Hence there can't be a vertex with a degree $50$ in $K_{50}$.

Is that right? or I'm wrong? would you help please.

Comment: One copy of $K_{50}$ plus $50$ unconnected vertices is not self-complimentary.

Comment: Can you please explain why?

Comment: There are $50^2$ edges between two parts.

Comment: As you take the complement, the edgeless part becomes $K_{50}$, the $K_{50}$ part becomes edgeless (which is good), and then you add $2500$ connections between the two parts (which is bad).

Comment: So is there any solution?

Comment: According to [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000171), there are 1110066810280143278346105974280473566442343518932753410230043852951741884650937161269266154280683695138791888354909588232985338008853156894716218336870085824373849823607818018769274953434300234421558703014674009040015882673946655163809537590676885893155260788167350906508845913270714972917156241354152457619380511504819821410166163636224 different self-complimentary graphs with $100$ nodes. So yes, there is "any solution". But you won't find it by just checking them all.

Comment: Are you asking whether there **exists** a self-complementary graph with $100$ vertices which has a vertex of degree $50$, or are you asking whether **every** self-complementary graph with $100$ vertices has a vertex of degree $50$?

Comment: my question is the first not the second

Comment: For every positive integer $k$ there is a self-complementary graph with $4k$ vertices in which half the vertices have degree $2k$ and the other half have degree $2k-1$; see the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3228707/question-about-self-complementary-graphs) for a very simple construction. In particular there is a self-complementary graph with $100$ vertices, $50$ vertices of degree $50$ and $50$ vertices of degree $49$.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clear that you are asking the firsr question and not the second.

Comment: On the other hand, for $k\ge2$ you can construct a self-complementary graph on $4k$ vertices with no vertices of degree $2k$; for example, a self-complementary graph on $100$ vertices where every vertex has degree $37$ or $62$.